# How to standardise in place in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a wide dataset:

```
id    x0  x1    x2   x3   x4   x5   ... x10000  Type 
1    40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  33      1    
2    35  35.75 36.5 26.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29      0
3    35  35.70 36.5 36.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29      1 
4    40  31.50 23.5 24.5 26.5 25   ...  33      1
 ... 
900  40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  23      0
```

with each row being a time series. I would like to standardise in place all values except for the last column, **with each row/time series as an independent distribution**. I am thinking about appending 2 columns `mean` and `std`(standard deviation) to the rightmost of the dataframe, and standardise using `apply`. But it sounds cumbersome and might make mistakes in the process. How can I do this and is there an easier way? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compute `mean` and `std` manually:

```
stats = df.iloc[:,1:-1].agg(['mean','std'], axis=1)     # axis=1 apply on rows
df.iloc[:, 1:-1] = (df.iloc[:, 1:-1]
                      .sub(stats['mean'], axis='rows')  # axis='rows' apply on rows
                      .div(stats['std'],axis='rows')
                   )
```

output:

```
      id          x0        x1         x2         x3         x4         x5     x10000    Type
 0     1   1.87515    0.297204  -0.681302  -0.681302  -0.681302  -0.769456   0.641003       1
 1     2   0.31841    0.499129   0.679848  -1.72974    0.679848   0.679848  -1.12734        0
 2     3  -0.0363456  0.218074   0.508839   0.508839   0.508839   0.508839  -2.21708        1
 3     4   1.81012    0.392987  -0.940787  -0.774066  -0.440622  -0.690705   0.64307        1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since `stats` is a separate df, do we have to specify the corresponding row/column of the positions of `mean` and `std` during the standardisation calculation by specifying the `i`?

Comment: No you don’t. The code should work as it is if your data looks similar to the sample, i.e. one column before and one after the time series.

Comment: You mean the `stats` and `data` have the same number of rows so the `stats` will match with the corresponding `data` rows?

Comment: Yes, that’s what the `axis`arguments are for.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1:

We can use `sklearn.preprocessing.scale`! Set `axis = 1` to scale data on each row!

This kind of data cleaning can be done nicely using sklearn.preprocessing.[Here is an official doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing)

Code:

```
# Generate data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(5,15,100),'B':np.random.randint(1,10,100),
                     'C':np.random.randint(0,10,100),'type':np.random.randint(0,2,100)})
data.head()

# filter columns and then standardlize inplace
data.loc[:,~data.columns.isin(['type'])] = scale(data.loc[:,~data.columns.isin(['type'])], axis = 1)
data.head()
```

Output:

> ```
>     A   B   C   type
> 0   12  8   2   0
> 1   5   2   9   1
> 2   14  5   2   1
> 3   5   7   6   0
> 4   8   1   4   0
>     A           B           C           type
> 0   1.135550    0.162221    -1.297771   0
> 1   -0.116248   -1.162476   1.278724    1
> 2   1.372813    -0.392232   -0.980581   1
> 3   -1.224745   1.224745    0.000000    0
> 4   1.278724    -1.162476   -0.116248   0
> ```

#### Method 2:

Just use lambda function if your dataset is not huge.

Code:

```
# Generate data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(5,15,100),'B':np.random.randint(1,10,100),
                     'C':np.random.randint(0,10,100),'type':np.random.randint(0,2,100)})
data.head()

# filter columns and than standardlize inplace
data.loc[:,~data.columns.isin(['type'])] = data.loc[:,~data.columns.isin(['type'])].\
apply(lambda x: (x  - np.mean(x))/np.std(x), axis = 1)
data.head()
```

Output:

> ```
>     A   B   C   type
> 0   12  8   2   0
> 1   5   2   9   1
> 2   14  5   2   1
> 3   5   7   6   0
> 4   8   1   4   0
>     A           B           C           type
> 0   1.135550    0.162221    -1.297771   0
> 1   -0.116248   -1.162476   1.278724    1
> 2   1.372813    -0.392232   -0.980581   1
> 3   -1.224745   1.224745    0.000000    0
> 4   1.278724    -1.162476   -0.116248   0
> ```

#### Speed compare:

**Method 1 is faster then method 2.**

Method 1:  **2.03 ms** ± 205 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit -r 100 -n 100
data.loc[:,~data.columns.isin(['type'])] = scale(data.loc[:,~data.columns.isin(['type'])], axis = 1)
```

Method 2:  **3.06 ms** ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit -r 100 -n 100
data.loc[:,~data.columns.isin(['type'])].apply(lambda x: (x  - np.mean(x))/np.std(x), axis = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please also advise how to further standardise in place using the `mean` and `std` columns?

Comment: So I would like to standardise the values in the dataframe and replace the original values with the standardised ones

Comment: @nilsinelabore Use `sklearn.preprocessing.scale` ! And `scipy.stats.zscore` can do the same thing. This kind of thing usually can be done nicely using built-in functions in  `scipy` and `sklearn.preprocessing`

Comment: Maybe more interesting should be test 1K, 100K, 1M rows ;)

Comment: @jezrael You are right, `scale` is slower(30% - 40%) than apply when testing with 100K+ rows. How did you know that, from the source code of `scale`?

Comment: @Travis - No, I have no idea about it. Reason my comment was sometimes performance is different in large data like in small ;)